# Detect when user enters data into edittext immediately shows answer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

How is it possible to detect if a character is inputted into an EditText which makes it from 0 to 1 characters long and then perform some action?

Answer (score 25):

Since you have a rather abstract question, let me attempt an equally generic answer:

In your `onCreate()`, declare and cast your `EditText`

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

And then, **outside** the `onCreate()`, setup the `filterTextWatcher` like this:

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // DO THE CALCULATIONS HERE AND SHOW THE RESULT AS PER YOUR CALCULATIONS

        int radius = 0;
        radius = Integer.valueof(s.toString);
        double area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

**EDIT:**

Updated code with possible calculation. (*UNTESTED CODE: I JUST TYPED IT IN WITHOUT TESTING IT. MODIFY WHERE NECESSARY*)

Read more about [TextWatcher's here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

And here are a few examples to get you started:

1. http://www.android-ever.com/2012/06/android-edittext-textwatcher-example.html
2. http://www.cybernetikz.com/blog/android-textwatcher-example/
3. http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=22b00052-dad0-4e09-a07e-b74f115ab247
4. http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-edittext-change-listener.html

Comment: for example to find area of circle just by entering radius into edittext i need answer below to this edittext field

Comment: @user2019287: Radius based on what? Area, Diameter, Circumference? Besides, you should be able to code in your formulas eh fella? Get your formula here: [Radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius).

Comment: area = math.pi * radius * radius

Answer (score 7):

You can use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) on your EditText and handle whatever you want to do with your user Input data Immediately.

here is an example of formatting immediately when user inputs data

```
final EditText EditTxtFinancialCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNewCpFinancialCode);


    EditTxtFinancialCode.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String a = "";
            boolean flag = true;
            String eachBlock[] = EditTxtFinancialCode.getText().toString().split("-");
            for (int i = 0; i < eachBlock.length; i++) {
                if (eachBlock[i].length() > 4) {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            if (flag) {

                EditTxtFinancialCode.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                            KeyDel = 1;
                        return false;
                    }

                });

                if (KeyDel == 0) {

                    if (((EditTxtFinancialCode.getText().length() + 1) % 5) == 0) {

                        if (EditTxtFinancialCode.getText().toString().split("-").length <= 2) {
                            EditTxtFinancialCode.setText(EditTxtFinancialCode.getText() + "-");
                            EditTxtFinancialCode.setSelection(EditTxtFinancialCode.getText().length());
                        }

                    }
                    a = EditTxtFinancialCode.getText().toString();
                } else {
                    a = EditTxtFinancialCode.getText().toString();
                    KeyDel = 0;
                }

            } else {
                EditTxtFinancialCode.setText(a);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: for example to find area of circle just by entering radius into edittext i need  answer below to this edittext field

Comment: +1, It is really a great answer by Arash. @lambda: please dont add stuff at your own. you can either comment on the answer or even you could post a separate answer, if you know your answer will create a difference.

Answer (score 6):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html

Make a listener.

```
   myTextBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int before, int count) {
   TextView myOutputBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myOutputBox);
   myOutputBox.setText(s);
   }
  });
```

see http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-edittext-text-change-listener.html