# get value of edittext without button event handling in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, event-handling

I am trying to show my database data into list view. And I want a text box in which user will enter age and according to that age list view will be updated. But I want to filter those result without button event. Is this possible? If so, then how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645209/how-can-i-filter-listview-data-when-typing-on-edittext-in-android
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625423/detect-when-user-enters-data-into-edittext-immediately-shows-answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391891/how-to-check-if-an-edittext-was-changed-or-not
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595313/how-to-get-a-result-data-to-edit-text-without-clicking-on-button
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-dynamically-update-a-listview-on-android

Answer (score 0):

You use a TextWatcher :

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}

});
```

Put you code inside `afterTextChanged`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. 
attach your `EditText` with an `addTextChangedListener()`

```
        your_editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s) ){
                //TODO filter data here
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```